# Rhc setup: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I've got a problem with executing command: rhc setup on Windows 8
I've got following output:
http://pastebin.com/JRhfK23B

Thanks
Tomasz

Comment: This should be posted as a bug report at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online instead of a question on stack overflow.com since it seems to be a tooling issue, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the new version of httpclient.

Use the older version instead:

```
sudo gem uninstall httpclient
sudo gem install httpclient -v 2.3.4
rhc setup
```